# How to call popToRootViewController() function from a separate view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

This is the function that pops the user back to the root in a UINavigationController:

```
func popToRoot() {
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

However, I need to call this function from the tab bar, which is obviously in an entirely different class and file and is not even in the navigation stack.

```
func moveToTab3(sender: UIButton!) {
    if CurrentContentController != containerStack[3] {
        moveToTab(3, animated: false)
    } else {
        // since you are already in this tab, popToRoot function goes here, but how?
    }
}
```

The problem is that .navigationController? is very particular and it appears has to be called from within the object it resides. How is this done?

Comment: May delegate back to tab bar controller and call the specific navigation controller do the trick? Or simply send a Notification to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I got you right, but to make possible to navigate to the root from current controller, you can detect the very top controller in your app using this:

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

Then you can access to that top controller and call popToRoot:

```
if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController() {
        // navigate to the root
               topController.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

It should work. Let me know if you need more info